# How to prove an operator is self adjoint on $P_n(R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $P_n(R)$ be the $(n+1)$-dimensional space of real polynomials of degree $\le n$. Define
\begin{gather}
  \langle f,g \rangle = \int_{-1}^{+1} f(t)g(t)\;dt.
\end{gather}
Show that this pairing is an inner product on $P_n(R)$ and that the operator
$\alpha: P_n(R) \rightarrow P_n(R)$ defined by
\begin{gather}
  \alpha(f)(t) = (1-t^2)f''(t) - 2t f'(t)
\end{gather}
is self-adjoint.

This is a sub-problem from problem set given to me in a proof based linear algebra course. My main question is how do I prove that this holds for any n. From what I can gather there is no discernible pattern with regards to an orthogonal basis which is from what I can gather the correct approach to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, we note, that we can write $\alpha(f)(t)=\big((1-t^2)f'(t)\big)'$. Using integration by parts we get:
\begin{align*}
\langle\alpha(f),g\rangle
&=\int_{-1}^1\alpha(f)(t)g(t)\mathrm dt
=\int_{-1}^1\big((1-t^2)f'(t)\big)'g(t)\mathrm dt \\
&\stackrel{\text{i.b.p.}}{=}\underbrace{(1-t^2)f'(t)g(t)\big\vert_{-1}^1}_{=0}
-\int_{-1}^1(1-t^2)f'(t)g'(t)\mathrm dt,
\end{align*}
which is symmetric under swapping $f$ and $g$.